# Generating routes between every point in a set of points in QGIS

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, routing

I'm looking for a way in which to generate a set of routes between every point in a layer.

To be clear, if I have four points [A,B,C,D] I want to get routes:

- A - B
- A - C
- A - D
- B - A
- B - C
- ...

... and so on for a total of (4*3=) 12 routes in this example; in fact, I have 35 points in my dataset so it's a bit more than that!

I can't ascertain a way to do this programmatically in QGIS using the Road Graph function or the OSM Route plugin (although it does give good results for a single route), and web searches have turned up nothing (most answers relate to routes that follow a number of points).

Preferably, as this is for cycling purposes, I'd like to use a routing service that would take the method of travel in to account, but not strictly necessary as I'd be happy just to use my line vector layer that I have for the area containing my points.

Comment: Why can't you generate the route as you need it? Is it imperative to store every possible combination and direction? There was a similar question to this about a week ago... that one received no response. I would suggest to iterate through your points, create a single route, store it (somehow) and then create a new single route if you must have all the routes solved and ready. Do you have any python ability? How are the solved routes to be consumed?

Comment: Yes, I do need all pf the routes at once as this forms part of network analysis. I do have python ability, though I've never used it in qgis before. The solved routes are to be consumed within qgis to create a heatmap.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`pgr_dijkstraCost`](https://docs.pgrouting.org/2.2/en/src/dijkstra/doc/pgr_dijkstraCost.html) from [PGRouting](https://docs.pgrouting.org/2.2/en/doc/index.html) in [many-to-many](https://docs.pgrouting.org/2.2/en/src/dijkstra/doc/pgr_dijkstra.html#dijkstra-many-to-many) mode.

Then you could run something like:

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstraCost(
    'select id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost from edge_table',
    ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5],
    ARRAY[1,2,3,4,5]);
```

Where the arrays are the ids of you start/finish nodes.